# Ruby Running in Parallel

Tags: ruby, jruby, em-synchrony

I currently have a small ruby script, which is connecting to the remote SSH servers and checking the size of the files and providing results whether it has been changed or not.

The issue is that there are around 10 servers like this. I would like to connect and check size in parallel and not one by one. Could anyone guide me how to accomplish that? I have also checked EM-Synchrony, but I assume that most efficient way would be to use JRuby.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue using Parallel gem for ruby. I have managed to decrease the total time for connect/checkup for all servers by 80%. Just in case someone reads this thread and finds it useful. Haven't managed to try JRuby though, which might be even more efficient.